Add Autodesk Construction Cloud members with roles using APS
how do you include roles when adding members to a project in APS? If I retrieve project members the structure matches the code below. Adding a member with the code below errors out if i include the role - If I send without the role details and the member is added. How do you add a member with a role?
The post request is url https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users:import
{
"users": [
    {
        "email": "Cill.gates@example.com",
        "products": [
            {
                "key": "projectAdministration",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "insight",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "docs",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "takeoff",
                "access": "administrator"
            },
            {
                "key": "designCollaboration",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "modelCoordination",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "build",
                "access": "none"
            },
            {
                "key": "cost",
                "access": "none"
            }
        ],
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": "f8b61c3d-1766-464b-a1b5-26bb7e38d647",
                "name": "Aviation Author"
            },
            {
                "id": "6bc27648-16ff-4a76-b2cd-26e15f66fd7c",
                "name": "Bridge Author"
            }
        ]
    }
]

}
the error is
{
"status": 400,
"type": "",
"id": "7ef142dc596186d6",
"errors": [
    {
        "detail": "Unknown property (not in schema)",
        "field": "/users/0/roles",
        "title": "Invalid or missing property",
        "type": ""
    }
],
"title": "Bad Request",
"detail": "Check errors array"

}

anyone looking at this the solution is to send the roleIds as an array. No need to send roles as names. Just have to first read the roles from the account to get Ids.
       "roleIds": [
            "7009862b-39be-4ccd-9f87-92ecb1d6bdb4",
            "5fc7c137-9b05-47b8-b9bc-8911ad91f667"
        ]


You can also get the roleIds from the endpoint at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projectsprojectId-users-userId-GET/
